# MongoDb Pivot on key value

Tags: mongodb, pivot, aggregation-framework

I am new bee in MongoDB, I have collection with key value pairs like below..
[input collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opVyR.jpg)

```
{"restaurantid" : NumberInt("1"), 
"Properties" : [ 
  { "Key" : "A", "Value" : NumberInt("25") }, 
  { "Key" : "B", "Value" : "StringValue" }, 
  { "Key" : "C", "Value" : ISODate("2017-02-09") } 
] }
```

I am looking result set as 
[Output Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAwQs.jpg)

```
{ "restaurantid" : NumberInt("1"), 
  "A" : NumberInt("25"), 
  "B" : "StringValue", 
  "C" : ISODate("2017-02-09") 
}
```

How do I get it without hardcoding "A", "B", "C" in the aggregation pipeline. My key value pairs are going to get bigger and is variable for given id

Answer (score 1):

> how do I get it without hardcoding “A”, “B”, “C” in the aggregation pipeline. My key value pairs are going to get bigger and is variable for given id

You can utilise new aggregation operator `$arrayToObject` ([SERVER-18794](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18794)) to pivot MongoDB keys. This operator currently is available in MongoDB v3.4.4+

For example, you can restructure your schema:

```
{
  "restaurantid" : NumberInt("1"),
  "Properties" : [
    { "k" : "A", "v" : NumberInt("25") },
    { "k" : "B", "v" : "StringValue" },
    { "k" : "C", "v" : ISODate("2017-02-09") }
  ]
}
```

Then you can utilise example [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) below:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {$project:{"tmp":{$arrayToObject:"$Properties"}, "restaurantid":"$resturantid"}}, 
    {$addFields:{"tmp.restaurantid":"$restaurantid"}}, 
    {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$tmp"}}
]);
```

See also [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). Depending on your use case, you could also take advantage of MongoDB flexible schema and reconsider your document model.